# hiding back button in ionic, angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to show and hide back button in different pages/views. I took reference from [Justin Noel](https://codepen.io/calendee/pen/eusfl):

```
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
    <ion-nav-back-button hide-back-button="{{hideBackButton}}">
    </ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-bar>
</body>
```

App controller to toggle button display:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
   var path = $location.path();
   if (path.indexOf('submit') != -1)
     $scope.hideBackButton = true;
   else
     $scope.hideBackButton = false;
})
```

But this doesnt work as controller is called only once but not at the change of view in different states. Also changing the value of $scope.hideBackButton from other controllers(linked to different states) does not have any effect on the button display.

Can anyone tell me how to toggle back-button display on each navigation. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I had exactly same problem today.

Simplest solution is to use $ionicNavBarDelegate:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $location, $ionicNavBarDelegate) {
   var path = $location.path();
   if (path.indexOf('submit') != -1)
     $ionicNavBarDelegate.showBackButton(false);
   else
     $ionicNavBarDelegate.showBackButton(true);
})
```

You can also wrap hideBackButton value in object and your code will work:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
   var path = $location.path();
   $scope.options = $scope.options || {};
   if (path.indexOf('submit') != -1)
     $scope.options.hideBackButton = true;
   else
     $scope.options.hideBackButton = false;
})
```

It works because in JS (as in many other languages) booleans are passed by value and object are passed by the referance and it affects how default Angular watchers are created. 
The downside of this method is that hidding of the button is not as smooth as in other ionic solutions.

Just in case, this is how your html should look like:

1st solution:

```
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
    <ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-bar>
</body>
```

2nd solution:

```
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
    <ion-nav-back-button hide-back-button="{{options.hideBackButton}}">
    </ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-bar>
</body>
```

Comment: For me it worked just adding the hide-back-button on the ion-view tag, like on this codepen: http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/eusfl

Answer (score 33):

The `hide-back-button` attribute on `<ion-view>` did the trick for me: `<ion-view hide-back-button="true">`

See the official documentation [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/directive/ionView/).

Comment: The best solution if you simply want to hide the back button without any condition. Thanks.

Answer (score 30):

```
$ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
    disableBack: true
  });

  $state.go('app.home');
```

Comment: $ionicViewService is deprecated. Use $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions

Comment: You know what? .
.>
>
>
>
You are just an awesome guy to help me in a decent way out :))

Answer (score 3):

Ionic 2 & 3:
`<ion-navbar [hideBackButton]="true">`

Answer (score 2):

A very simple way to achieve this is to apply the `menu-close` directive to your button/anchor. Technically it's meant for closing the menu, but you can use it on any link and it will bypass the slide animation & won't show the back button.

```
<a menu-close href="#/home">Home</a>
```

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/menuClose/

Comment: It works with ui-sref, but `menu-close` actually clears the history, that's why you don't see the back button (no back state). I think nfgf's answer is better.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
          disableBack: false,
          historyRoot: true
        });
```

That seems a good option to use, works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the cache settings so that when the page is reloaded the controller is called again:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/

Answer (score 1):

The `hide-back-button` attribute should be set on `ion-view` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with "hide-back-button", since it hides the menu and the back button.
Somehow `this.navCtrl.push` played with the back button, in case you want the menu to be displayed using `this.nav.setRoot(yourPage)`