# Ionic ui-router side-menu $ionicHistory

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I'm working on my first project in Ionic Framework. The app is using **ui-router** for state management and **ion-side-menu** for navigation. Even though states and navigation have been really smooth, I'm having trouble understanding transitions between states and the back button.

Scenario 1: The side menu has a list of the main states in the app and the user can navigate by tapping on them. When they do so and the transition ends successfully, I don't want the back button to appear at the top left instead of the side menu toggle. I want to see the toggle and the side menu again.

Scenario 2: When the user submits a post, I want the user to transition into the 'My Posts' state with the newly created post at the top (I already achieved this resolve in the state). So after the post is submitted I have: $state.go('app.myposts.list'); When the 'My Posts' is rendered, I see the back button at the top again, but I want the user to see the menu toggle.

I read the docs on both side-menu and ui-router, and $ionicHistory but I haven't been able to find the answer for what the true logic of this is. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `$ionicNavBarDelegate` which is explained in this Stack Overflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28830352/3423342